# react-native-fbsdk compilation error

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am trying to use https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk with the latest react-native 0.47.1 but am getting the following compilation error on Android after following all the installation steps:

```html
/home/gerhard/Projects/bounzapp/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBSDKPackage.java:61: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

PS.
When I run "react-native link" I also get the following but it might because I'm not running on a Mac, I'll have to confirm that later.

```html
gerhard@linux-clqp:~/Projects/bounzapp> react-native link
Scanning 680 folders for symlinks in /home/gerhard/Projects/bounzapp/node_modules (10ms)
rnpm-install info Android module react-native-fbsdk is already linked
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-fbsdk ios dependency
rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: Expected "/*", "//", or "{" but "<" found.
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

Expected "/*", "//", or "{" but "<" found.
```

Comment: have you try to remove the fbsdk package and reinstall it? you need to rerun the link also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly this is a known, and current issue.

There was quite a few issues with the recent releases of `react-native-fbsdk` (all for different reasons: `0.5.0`, `0.6.0`, and `0.6.1`). The tricky part is that some versions work on iOS while the other work on Android only depending on the version of RN that you run.

Since Facebook has removed Issues section on their GitHub, all the helpful information is scattered across their bug tracker, i.e.:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/257149274778275/
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/126967157938007/

and `react-native` Issues on GitHub, i.e.:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14670

[Pull requests](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pulls) section shines some light on current issues, i.e.:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/339

**At this point I'd recommend to stick to `react-native-fbsdk@0.5.1` on `react-native0.46.4` while all the above is resolved.**

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade the react-native-fbsdk version using

```
npm install react-native-fbsdk@0.6.0 --save
```

after that link using

```
react-native link react-native-fbsdk
```

then update the react-native-fbsdk

```
npm update react-native-fbsdk
```